# Javascript function not load on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

a have a simple application wrote on Rails 4.2.3 and i use Heroku to deploy. I use bootstrap and it works fine after rake assets:precompile, but, i have one pure-javascript function on application.js, and works perfectly on localhost, but on heroku, simply doesnt work.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

function getCEP() {
    if ($.trim($("#endereco_cep").val()) != "") {

      $("#lbcep").html(" Pesquisando...")
    <!-- JQuery que recebe o objeto serializado via ajax. -->
        $.getScript("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep="+$("#endereco_cep").val(), function(){
      <!-- Atribuindo os valores para os componentes da página-->
    if(resultadoCEP["resultado"]){
        $("#endereco_tipo").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["tipo_logradouro"]));
        $("#endereco_endereco").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["logradouro"]));
        $("#endereco_bairro").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["bairro"]));
        $("#endereco_cidade").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["cidade"]));
        $("#endereco_estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"]));
        $("#endereco_numero").focus();
       } else {
          alert("Cep não encontrado.");
       }
       $("#lbcep").html(" CEP")});
    }
    else {
        alert("Informe um cep.");
    }
}
```

I have only this javascript function in my project, and not work. I'm already set
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false on my config/application.rb
and set Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.scss *.js ) in my config/initializers/assets.rb. I clean and precompile again and still not work. Please, i need some help. I search in many topics and follow all the instructions but i still not resolve this. Waiting for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues you could have:

- Precompilation
- JS firing the function

--

[Precompilation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) is the standard issues on Heroku (you can use `Aytan Leobowitz`'s answer to fix it), however, I don't think it's your issue because you said your CSS works (`bootstrap`)...

For the record, if you wanted to precompile before pushing to Heroku, we do as the other answer suggests except using:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
git add .
git commit -a -m "JS"
git push heroku master
```

--

This would lead me to your other problem - JS is not firing.

Using `javascript` / `jquery` in a Rails application, there are several things you'll quickly discover. The first is that running a "naked" function just isn't reliable (which is what you have). You need to bind it to the `document` or an `event`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

var getCEP = function()  {
    if ($.trim($("#endereco_cep").val()) != "") {

      $("#lbcep").html(" Pesquisando...")
    <!-- JQuery que recebe o objeto serializado via ajax. -->
        $.getScript("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep="+$("#endereco_cep").val(), function(){
      <!-- Atribuindo os valores para os componentes da página-->
    if(resultadoCEP["resultado"]){
        $("#endereco_tipo").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["tipo_logradouro"]));
        $("#endereco_endereco").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["logradouro"]));
        $("#endereco_bairro").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["bairro"]));
        $("#endereco_cidade").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["cidade"]));
        $("#endereco_estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"]));
        $("#endereco_numero").focus();
       } else {
          alert("Cep não encontrado.");
       }
       $("#lbcep").html(" CEP")});
    }
    else {
        alert("Informe um cep.");
    }
}

$(document).ready(getCEP);
```

The above is your likely issue.

The simple fact you are relying on the event firing on load is not enough - Rails has `turbolinks` and some other complexity which prevents "naked" JS from loading off the bat.

Instead, you need to use `$(document).ready...` or, if using [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) `$(document).on("page:load"...` - *binding* the function to either an `event` with an element, or the `document` load events.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to precompile your assets locally.

[Rails Asset Pipeline on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add -A
git commit -m "Precompiled assets"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: you can also do at point 2 `git add .` and 3 as `git commit -a -m "Precompiled assets"`

Answer (score 0):

Great, Rich! You're the man!
I create a separated file called getcpf.js to function, and call the function using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#endereco_cep").blur(function(){
    getCep();
  });
})
```

I see a recomendation to never put functions on application.js. So, i use a file especific for funciont. I compile and works perfectly! :)
Thanks so much!